# Can I use "pique" (verb) to mean I am stimulated by something?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-in-context

Does this sound natural?

> "This book has **piqued** me. Now, I love reading."

If that doesn't work, why? What's the reason? Could you suggest another verb that works?

The definition I got from Merriam Webster: Learner's Dictionary.

> 1 chiefly US : to cause (curiosity or interest)
>
> The package piqued [=sparked, aroused] my curiosity.
>
> Brightly colored objects pique a baby's interest.

Comment: Yes, but are you sure you mean that? How about you look it up and post the definitions? Perhaps you mean: has piqued my interest.

Comment: @Lambie I have looked up. I meant to say "that book has stimulated my mood." So that my mood becomes increased in a positive way.

Comment: Hmm, "mood" alone usually doesn't increase or decrease or get stimulated.

Comment: pique can be positive or negative. Yours suggests **annoyance**, to be frank.

Comment: So, I can't use that way in the positive sense? Understood. Then back to my question, which verb is appropriate?

Comment: According to the definition you quoted, in this sense, "pique" means "cause", and it is only applied to the nouns "curiosity" and "interest". That should give you two reasons why "This book has piqued me" doesn't work.

Comment: @gotube ok. Could you suggest another verb that works? Actually, I asked about an appropriate verb that works with the sentence. And the sentence above is my attempt.

Comment: "This book has piqued my interest"

Comment: feel irritated or resentful. Oxford Dictionary
"she was piqued by his curtness" It can be negative. She was piqued by the book. As I said at the beginning, you need to tell us which you want. And I point out that I was the first to say here: pique my interest.